# I forgot to do git bisect reset: what are the consequences?

Tags: git, git-bisect

I was tracking down a problem in my codebase with `git bisect` and I forgot to do a `reset` at the end.  I'm now on another branch, in the middle of my work.  What happens if I do it now?  Do I need to wait until I'm done with this branch?

Comment: You mean, you starting adding changes to your code and now you don't know how to move them to where you actually need to work?

Comment: @eftshift0: I don't understand exactly what you're describing, but I'm pretty sure that it's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking how to exit the `git bisect` process non-destructively, since I forgot to do the `reset` when I was done bisecting and git still thinks I'm bisecting, and is waiting for a `git bisect reset`, at which time it will do stuff that I don't want it to do.  I just want it to stop waiting for any `git bisect reset`.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as tacking on `HEAD` (or any other commit) on the end, to avoid going back to the commit you were on before bisecting:

```
git bisect reset HEAD
```